# failed to fetch platform cordova-browser@ 5.0.1

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, platform

I've tried many ways but still can not run, so did on `Android` platform and `iOS` .. is there any help?

[image]

Comment: What is your cordova version?

Comment: i use cordova 8.0.0.. any solution for me?

Comment: Is adding cordova-browser@latest working?